# Scala grouping list into list tuples with one shared element

Tags: scala, functional-programming

What would be short functional way to split list

```
List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) into List((1,2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `zip` the list with its *tail*:

```
val list = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
// list: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

list zip list.tail
// res6: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,2), (2,3), (3,4), (4,5))
```

Answer (score 5):

(assuming you don't care if you nested pairs are Lists and not Tuples)

Scala collections have a `sliding` window function:

```
@ val lazyWindow = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).sliding(2)
lazyWindow: Iterator[List[Int]] = non-empty iterator
```

To realize the collection:

```
@ lazyWindow.toList
res1: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 2), List(2, 3), List(3, 4), List(4, 5))
```

You can even do more "funcy" windows, like of length 3 but with step 2:

```
@ List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).sliding(3,2).toList
res2: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 2, 3), List(3, 4, 5))
```

Answer (score 1):

I have always been a big fan of `pattern matching`. So you could also do:

```
val list = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

  def splitList(list: List[Int], result: List[(Int, Int)] = List()): List[(Int, Int)] = {
    list match {
      case Nil => result
      case x :: Nil => result
      case x1 :: x2 :: ls => splitList(x2 :: ls, result.:+(x1, x2))
    }
  }

  splitList(list)
  //List((1,2), (2,3), (3,4), (4,5), (5,6))
```